# Image storage location

Tags: database

What's the best place to store an image?

In the database? or in the Filesystem?

What if I have multiple servers? Would filesystem storage still work?

Thank you

Comment: possible duplicate of [Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)

Answer (score 1):

This question has been answered many times before, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app).

I'll add from myself that, since that time (2 years ago) I've come to trust external storage services, like [Amazon S3](http://aws.amazon.com/s3/). They are fairly cheap, provide most benefits of filesystem storage and also scale well.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely you should store images in the filesystem or your database become huge.

Also you can use NFS (http://nfs.sourceforge.net/) to make images storage on one server and use "share" directory.

Or you can use rsync for syncing you images content on different servers.