# What's the best way to setup a user post image uploading system?

Tags: python, html, sql, django, image

I'm using django.  I want a user to upload an image for a user post, but I'm not sure the backend of this.  Should I setup a db with the url of the image, a folder for the user, a folder inside of the post, and the image finally in that folder? What is the best (fastest, efficient, nonconfusing) way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the built in django [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField).  This essentially is set up to store and reference a url relative to a media dir on the webserver.

There is a pretty basic example [here](http://www.nitinh.com/2009/02/django-example-filefield-and-imagefield/).

EDIT:
For your own implementation outside of django most people would implement it in a similar way to how Django's imagefield works.  Basically, you story a reference to a file in a filesystem somewhere, and store the actual file on the filesystem.

You can store the actual image in the database but I think most people prefer to not store it in the database.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app) stackoverflow question has a lot of info about why one would want to do it one way or another.  I myself have done this both ways and like storing them in the filesystem more than in the database in most cases.

Comment: k thx, i'll try that, but if I were to do this myself, using another language such as php, how would the backend work?

Comment: I added info about general implentation outside of django to my answer since it was too long for a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#imagefield) which comes built in in with django. The good thing about this it stores and manages it within Django, you can resize and get url to the image all using PIL and Django helper methods.

This is the best way for deployment as well, once you decide to deploy you will be able to tweak the system to best serve up static files, as supposed to managing it yourself.

Goodluck.