# Storing image in database vs file system (is this a valid use case?)

Tags: mysql, image

I have an application where every user gets there own database and runs from the same file system folder. (the database is determined by sub domain)

Storing in the filesystem could lead to conflict. I'd imagine the images upload would be small. (I would scale them down before storing)

Is it ok in this case to store in database?

(I know this has been asked a lot)

I also want to make my application easy to install and creating a writable folder is hard for some people)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take the contrary view from Nathanial -- I find it easier to use the data base to store opaque data like images. When you back up the data base, you automatically get a backup of the images. Also, you can retrieve, update, or delete the image along with all the other data in integrated SQL queries; keeping the files separately means writing much more complex code that has to go out to the file system to maintain data integrity every time you issue certain SQL queries. Locking can be a big problem, and transaction processing (especially rollback) even bigger.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you've already sort of talked yourself into it, but in my experience it's better to store files in a filesystem and data in a database. Use GUID's for the file names if you are worried about a conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Pasting my answer from a similar post: I have implemented both solutions (file system and database-persisted images) in previous projects. In my opinion, you should store images in your database. Here's why:

1. File system storage is more complicated when your app servers are
   clustered. You have to have shared storage. Even if your current
   environment is not clustered, this makes it more difficult to scale
   up when you need to
2. You should be using a CDN for your static
   content anyways, and set your app up as the origin. This means that
   your app will only be hit once for a given image, then it will be
   cached on the CDN. CloudFront is dirt cheap and simple to set
   up...there's no reason not to use it. Save your bandwidth for your
   dynamic content.
3. It's much quicker (and thus cheaper) to develop
   database persisted images
4. You get referential integrity with
   database persisted images. If you're storing images on the file
   system, you will inevitably have orphan files with no matching
   database records, or you'll have database records with broken file
   links. This WILL happen...it's just a matter of time. You'll have to
   write something to clean these up.

Anyways, my two cents.