# Sharing/storing video

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008, video

I need a way to show a grid of videos, where if you hover over one, it will show a 3 second preview. This is all written in ASP.Net using C# and SQL Server 2008.

Questions I have to ask myself -

- Would these be stored in a database or on the file system?
- How to show these videos? - this is the easy part, just looking for opinions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "Would these be stored in a database or on the file system?" http://stackoverflow.com/q/561447/1209450

Comment: "How to show these videos? - this is the easy part, just looking for opinions." You can show it in Repeater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Storage:** there are so many aspects to that decision. Many will say to put the files on the file system but then again that depends on whether you want easy disaster recovery, how you scale, whether your file system or DB supports better caching, etc.

**How to show the videos:** If your UI is in Flash, that's probably the easiest. If not, you'd probably need to generate a GIF with 3 seconds of video as a preview for each video, which you then load dynamically when the cursor hovers over the still thumbnail.