# Handle images in JSF

Tags: java, performance, jsf, image-processing

I am currently developing a website in which several images will be displayed on a single page. In light of performance, I'm searching for the best way to handle thes images.

First, I will explain my needs. The back-end of the website consists of a CMS in which images can be uploaded (and maybe resized by the user so the image will have the neede ratio of width/height). These images will be displayed on several pages in de website, requested by (hopefully) many users.

Secondly, I will shortly describe my environment. I am developing in Java EE, using JSF as front-end. I am  using multiple libraries like Prime Faces et cetera.

I have done some research and it seems there are dozens of solutions, but I don't know in which direction to search. E.g.:

- Saving images in database
- Saving images as static images by using for example filestreams

So in short:

- Which way of saving and requesting images would be best in this case?
- What library would you advice to serve me in this?
- Is there a JSF-solution to manually resize images?
- Would ImageJ be the best solution to generate thumbnails? If not, what would be?

If any other details are needed, I'm happy to provide them.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: JSF will help you generating HTML to the client and will facilitate the request handling. The way you decide to save/request your images would be reflected in the requests made by JSF (like a plain Servlet make a request). For more info about image handling in web applications, see [Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/561447/1065197). Note that the solutions offered could talk about .net or other platforms, so keep with the main concepts: web application, request handling, save in disk/filestream, these concepts can be implemented in Java/JSF.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't worry about performance until it becomes an issue. I would perhaps worry more about auditability, maintainability etc.

In order to make a future change easy, however, is abstract away your image store such that you can easily replace (say) a file-based system, with a database system (or a cloud-storage solution, or, or...).

That way you can easily substitute one for another and compare/constrast if need be, or simple swap out your implementation at a later date.

Answer (score 0):

So..

- Saving images as files is best
- After some research it seems that PrimeFaces offers ImageCropper
- File Upload can be achieved using PrimeFaces' FileUpload

But still, I have seen many discussions on Image Manipulation by Java and the best tooling for this. Some say ImageJ would be great, others don't. Is there any reason why I should go with one or another?

Comment: I don't know if someone would give you a good answer on this. The best will be to make proof of concepts with ImageJ and other libraries to make up your mind about this.

Comment: Hmm maybe you're right. Just like other discussions on the internet there may not be a 'best' answer. At least now I know that saving images as files is best, instead of clogging the database with them.