# How to retrieve link to an image from CakePHP to Android?

Tags: php, android, image, cakephp, android-networking

I'm fairly new with CakePHP and images so bear with me. You can assume I'm using the latest version.

I'm trying to build an Android application which can display images retrieved from the server.

Suppose I have an image in the assets folder called football.jpg. How would I store this in the database and then how would I output this to the Android application? Do I send only the link or do I send the whole image over? If it is just the link, does this mean I would have to reconnect to the server with the link and then get the image? Sorry if this doesn't make sense. Still trying to get my head around it.

Comment: You only need to send the link for the image to the Android application. But, if you want it to be saved for offline use, you're probably going to need an Android equivalent of php's file_get_contents and save it somewhere on the phone (Android is not my forte).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a word of caution, it's probably better to store the file on the server's file system and store the path to the file in the database. The reason behind this is that BLOBs are stored in a different area on the file system to all your other typical data and in terms of retrieval, its not a great deal faster.

Here's a link to what I mean: [Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)

With regards to returning it to your Android app, you can send files in the response object (http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html#cake-response-file):

```
public function sendFile($id) {
    $file = $this->Attachment->getFile($id);
    $this->response->file($file['path']);
    //Return reponse object to prevent controller from trying to render a view
    return $this->response;
}
```

This should give you finer control over what files are returned to your client.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying. I assume the response object will be JSON/XML? If I had a list of images retrieved at once, for example, a list of images with a category of sports with I respond back to the Android app as a list of image links. Do I have to use another AsyncTask and then reconnect again? Sorry, I'm a bit fuzzy on how this works

Comment: Also, you used the "Attachment" object. What is that? I'm just wondering, how would I give the full URL. I don't want to do "www.example.com/public/assets/image.jpg". Is there nothing like, $Assets->link(image.jpg); where it'll generate the full URL for me automatically?

Comment: The response object would be the image file prepended with the HTTP headers. Yes, your implementation would have to make n+1 calls (where n is the number of images). The first call would be to request all the paths to the images (which could be a JSON/XML) and then individual calls for each image (e.g. www.example.com/categoryImages/football). The `$this->Attachment` object is a CakePHP model (e.g. in a database). So in the code above, they get the file record from the database using the ID passed in the request and then assign the `file()` in the response to the path field of the record.