# What is the Better Idea to store Images?

Tags: asp.net, image-processing

What would be the **better Idea to store Images** ? Is it Database (or) any hosting ?
(or) Is there any other idea to store images using ASP.net.

Comment: The best idea to store images is on the hard disk. - programming on asp.net is not change the idea behind the storage of big media files.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, @Aristos. The thing while working with web application. Please see the last line (using ASP.net).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

The standard answer is to use both; database holds the location of the files and the file server holds the actual data.

The main advantages of doing this are listed in [Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server and version 2008 or higher then its worth to store image in file stream. It contains both advantage of storing image in files and database.

Here you can find more information about it from following links.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933993(v=sql.105).aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/128657/How-Do-I-Use-SQL-File-Stream

Regards,