# image does not get retrieved from database into html form using php

Tags: php, html

> Getimage.php

```
<?php
$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="tiger";

/* @var $dbhandle type */
 $dbhandle = \mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");

/* @var $select type */
$select= \mysqli_select_db($dbhandle,"sample")
     or mysqli_error($dbhandle);
 /* @var $itemId type */
$itemId= (\filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'name'));
$sql="select img from starterveg where itemId=$itemId";
$res2=mysqli_query($dbhandle,$sql);
$row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($res2);
mysqli_close($dbhandle);
header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
echo $row['img'];
?>

<body>
<img src="Getimage.php?itemId=oepsv1086" alt="image" id="img1">
</body>
```

>
 I'm not able to display the image from database into the html for.Instead the alt message only appears inside the html form

Comment: i think you need to echo 'yourimagepath'.$row['img'];

Comment: can u jus give the example?

Comment: the img column in the database has the blob datatype

Comment: Is your code sample one or two separate files ?

Comment: mysqli connect also requires the database, else you cant read it out where you trying to pick it up from. You later open the db, but you can put that in one (I asume its sample) but you can better put that in your $dbhandle variable.

Comment: sample is my database

Answer (score 0):

Try in your getimage.php

```
    header("Content-type:image/jpeg");
    stripslashes ($row['img']);

    echo $row['img'];
```

***storing image in DB is not recommended.*

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377686/insert-view-image-into-from-a-mysql-db/22377869#22377869)

EDIT 2 >>

```
$itemId= (\filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'name'));
```

this should be

`$itemId= (\filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'itemId')); #as you are passing itemid in get`

**EDIT 3>>**

You were missing single quotes (') in where query , that was causing errors

it should be

```
$sql="select img from starterveg where itemId='$itemId'";
```

Comment: Have you checked the reference ??  you can view my PHP class for doing this here http://www.phpclasses.org/package/6834-PHP-Validate-and-resize-uploaded-image-files.html

Comment: I hope in getimage.php file you are not echoing any other thing before echoing Image ..!

Comment: ya i echo only the image.. i tried the reference still does not work

Comment: <img src="getimage.php?itemId=<?php echo $row['img'];?> " alt="image" id="img1"> this is how i changed my src tag..but no change..

Comment: ya there are 30 jpeg images stored in the database in blob datatype in mysql database

Comment: <body>
<img src="Getimage.php?itemId=oepsv1086" alt="image" id="img1">
</body> <----- **its in getimage .php ?????**

Comment: no it is in another page called customer .php where i need to display my images

Comment: so when you directly access the page with any image id in url param , what does it displays without header("Content-type:image/jpeg"); ??

Comment: do i have to add in customer.php page? Can u explain clearly what mistake i have done??

Comment: see my 2nd edit , you are passing **itemId** but trying to fetch 'name' get request param in getimage.php page

Comment: it is the typographical error.. i have changed that.. Sorry still not getting what im expecting..

Comment: so you cahanged that $itemId= (\filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'name')); in your code ?

Comment: yes i have changed as $itemId= (\filter_input(\INPUT_GET,'itemId'));

Comment: what is your primary key for table image ?? its itemid only I guess

Comment: do one thing access getimage.php directly from browser with a valid itemid eg **Getimage.php?itemId=this_should_be_valid_id_fromDB**

Comment: so do i have to give this inside src?

Comment: its online , can I access that uri ?

Comment: actually in the img field the images are stored as [BLOB -16B]

Comment: ok thats fine , I need to see your complete code and DB structure

Comment: this runs on a server ..i think without server it s not possible to access

Comment: I asked for web URL to access

Comment: u need the Getimage file and the customer.php page file in the mail?

Comment: yes all the concerened code , plus the db table(image) structure