# Uploading image to mysql using html and php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to upload a image from my html form to my mysql blob column.
I feel like the php file isn't receiving the file based off of all the testing to try to figure out what is not working.

relevant HTML code:

```
<form action = "insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="myimage">
<input type="submit" name = "Insert" value="Insert">
</form>
```

relevant PHP code:

```
$imagename=$_FILES["myimage"]["name"];

if(getimagesize($FILES['myimage']['tmp_name']) == FALSE){
    echo "no image";
}
//Get the content of the image and then add slashes to it 
$imagetmp = addslashes($_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name']);
$image = file_get_contents($imagetmp);
$sql = "INSERT INTO locations (image) VALUES ('$image')";
$res = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
```

I believe the php isn't recieving the file because I always get my "no image" echoed.

Comment: in form tag add first `<form action = "insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">`

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud ok I have done that now I get a You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Comment: storing the image data in the db is potentially going to make the db grow to a huge size very quickly

Comment: Please do not use `mysql_query` it is deprecated from php latest version.Use mysqli instead of that.

Comment: @RamRaider that is fine for now

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud ok so what would the line look like?  And would that fix the error?

Comment: tell me about the variable `$image`

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud its all in the code I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before inserting into the database I think you should `base64_encode` the data.

```
$imagename=$_FILES["myimage"]["name"];
if( getimagesize( $FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'] ) == FALSE ){
    exit( "no image" );
}

$image = base64_encode( file_get_contents( $_FILES['myimage']['tmp_name'] ) );
```

To use `mysqli` you could do something like:

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "foo";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "bar";

$db=new mysqli( $servername, $username, $password, $dbname );

$sql='insert into `locations` set `image`=?';
$stmt=$db->prepare( $sql );

$stmt->bind_param( 's', $image );
if( $stmt ) $stmt->execute();

$db->close();

$sql = "INSERT INTO `locations` (`image`) VALUES ('$image')";
$res = mysql_query( $sql ) or die( mysql_error() );
```

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error you faced you did not notice.I find a problem in your code.I think it should be work.

```
<form action = "insert.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

**Warning**

This extension was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.

Comment: What would the query line look like for mysqli?

Comment: Just go through the link it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22377686/insert-view-image-into-from-a-mysql-db . After posting answer of your specific question do not edit/add anything to your question code.Beacuse someone give the answer according to your first question.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

it's stupid idea that uploading image to mysql database. Upload image to folder on your server and write path (path to image) to database. That is optimal variant and better.

Comment: This is not an answer of this question.It can be a comment section.Please be smart in StackOverflow.Thanks.