# How to store a large amounts of photos and videos using Django

Tags: python, django

I have a huge desire to create a website that hosts a bunch of educational videos and photos and I'd like to write it in Django, but I'm not sure how to go about it. I have 3months of Django, and year+ of HTML/CSS/JS/jQuery/Bootstrap/SQL under my belt. With Django I have created several mini projects, but nothing this serious. I assume that this is feasible, but don't know which tools I should consider. What will be the best place for storing uploaded images and videos using Django as backend? Should Include Celery, Redis and AWS S3 in my project?

I plan to host my project on digitial ocean using their  standard $10/month plan,  does anyone think/know if this will be enough to cover 5k users per year and their uploaded photos and videos?
Sorry guys I know this is a lot of questions ( and you dont have to answer all), but this is bugging me alot and before starting the actual coding I want to plan everything properly to limit any chances for failure. Any suggestions/pointers much appreciated.

Comment: 5k users per second/minute/hour/day/month?

Comment: 5k users per year.

Comment: that would be like 14 users per day, so you can use a $5/month droplet to cover up to 1000 users per day (if you know how to configure the server and optimize the Django ORM querys)

Comment: @Horion for video hosting I'd definitely recommend using S3 since you might have some problem with crossbrowser compatibility depending on your host, with 14 users per day you can manage to do something easily so don't over engineer your project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Storing file path in database, and putting your images and other media files on file system is generally the right way to go.

And [FileField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#filefield) will help you!

I found following answers to other questions have covered your problem, you might be interested in followings:

[Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app?rq=1)

[Storing Images in DB - Yea or Nay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748/storing-images-in-db-yea-or-nay)