# Yii2 Render an image base64 in DetailView

Tags: php, yii2, base64

I have a base64 image, and I want to display it in the following dataView

```
<?= DetailView::widget([
    'model' => $model,
    'attributes' => [
        'nome:ntext',
        'img1:ntext', // here is the base64 string that is also accessed by "$ model-> img1"
    ],
]) ?>
```

I tried the following code, but it did not work

```
[
    'attribute' => 'img1',
    'value' => base64_decode($model->img1),
    'format' => ['image', ['width' => '100', 'height' => '100']]
],
```

Comment: How did it not work? What's happening?

Comment: Hello. when you run the page, it does not show any results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
[
    'attribute' => 'img1',
    'value' => 'data:image/png;base64,' . $model->img1,
    'format' => ['image', ['width' => '100', 'height' => '100']]
],
```

or

```
[
    'attribute' => 'img1',
    'value' => 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' . $model->img1,
    'format' => ['image', ['width' => '100', 'height' => '100']]
],
```

depending on image type.

---

BTW: If you're storing images in database you may want to read [Store pictures as files or in the database for a web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app) (and tens of duplicates). It is quite likely that you will have a lot of problems because of this approach.

Comment: It works, and thanks for the tip, it really can cause problems.