# ASP.NET Core storing large amount of image files with web API

Tags: database, asp.net-core, filesystems, storage

I've been googling for a while now, but I'm not exactly sure what it is called that I'm looking for. I'm building an application where one module is collecting images through a camera and sending them over the network to another modules that stores them. The projects are written in APS.NET Core with Angular front-end. I'm looking for an efficient way to store and transfer these images. I've read that putting them as BLOB objects in a SQL database is not efficient, so I'm thinking of using a file system and storing the location in a database. I would like to retrieve them through a http request (although I'm open to suggestions). Is there any such project available that I could use as an example?

So in summary:

- Store many images on a network location efficiently (maybe compressed)
- Using ASP.NET Core preferably
- Retrieve images over the network as well (http?)
- I will host it myself in the closed network, so no cloud services like cloudinary (although this is basically exactly what functionality I need).

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

**EDIT**

After some more research I that found the closest to what I'm looking for is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/561447/store-pictures-as-files-or-in-the-database-for-a-web-app?rq=1) answer saying that the images should be spread over different folders and the location stored in the database. Now I'm still looking for an example project like this... Does anyone know an open source project that works like this and is written in ASP.NET Core?

Comment: I’ve developed a MVC5 project that stores the images in the file system and path info in dB. Currently I ‘m redeveloping similar project with .net Core. The solution has three projects, one for the control panel and image upload, second one is web api to store the resized images, and the third one is the public end user interface where the images are actually displayed. I will share a sample on github and give the link here after finishing.

Comment: This sounds a lot like what I'm trying to do. It would be very interesting to see the result when you are finished.

Comment: @LazZiya what's the status after 3 years?? :)

Comment: @Shahroozevsky thank you for reminding me, frankly speaking I totally forgot about this issue :( but actually I did the project, then added too many other features and now I am using it as my own CMS, but I think it is too much to share as a solution for this issue here. (Not a promise) but I will try to make a clean one and share once I have time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can and probably should use a CDN, eg AWS S3 to solve your image files storage issue. This would also be a very scale-able solution with numerous configuration features:

- Temporary public links to access file via HTTP
- Access control
- Versioning
- etc.

You probably won't find the full solution source code online, but the main part of uploading a file is a pretty common problem. See [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/HLuploadFileDotNet.html) for the start.

Comment: But this option is cloud based meaning that I need to have a connection to the internet, which this system doesn't have. I can only use the local network.